Redux Toolkit Slice is producing wrong type "WritableDraft<AppApiError> when using extraReducer
I typed data and error for my initial state as MednannyAppointments[] and AppApiError. When hovering over state.error or state.data in my extraReducer calls the type is always WritableDraft. I don't understand where that comes from.
If you look at my extra reducer function I already typed everything.
Extra Reducer Function
export const getAppointments = createAsyncThunk<
  Appointment[],
  string,
  { rejectValue: AppAPIError }
>("something/getAppointments", async (vsnr: string) => {
  return await fetchFromAPI<Appointment[]>(
    ROUTES.GET_APPOINTMENTS,
    "GET",
    {
      XXX
    }
  );
});

Slice
type InitialAppointmentState = {
  data: Appointment[];
  isFetching: boolean;
  error: AppAPIError;
};

const initialAppointmentState: InitialAppointmentState = {
  data: null,
  isFetching: false,
  error: null
};

const appointments = createSlice({
  name: "appointments",
  initialState: initialAppointmentState,
  reducers: {
    updateAppointement(state, action: PayloadAction<Appointment>) {
      state.data = state.data.map((appointment) =>
        appointment.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : appointment
      );
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getAppointments.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.data = action.payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(getAppointments.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(getAppointments.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      
      // state.error has a type of WritableDraft<AppApiError> instead of AppApiError
      state.error = action.payload;
    });
  }
});


RTK uses immer library under the hood to support immutability. So entire structure (including nested props) is wrapped in a Proxy that tracks mutations without mutating the original object.
More details here and here RTK #5: Why Immer inside a starter kit? and also some details about immer

But usually there is no WritableDraft type in my state. I think i don't understand how immer influences that.

I am observing that WritableDraft  appears in TypeScript when there are extraReducers. Try to  just remove them temporarily and WritableDraft disappears in typings.
When I put an instance of class to Redux store (which is not proxied by immer) I get in types "WritableDraft" and it breaks  TypeScript...
Unacceptable behavior of Redux...

Yes thats exactly what I experienced.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
